# How to get SignalR endpoints list in vNext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core, jwt

**Problem**

I need to determine if current request is being served by SignalR.

**Question**

How can I get a list of `SignalR` endpoints to check if the endpoint is there

OR

A way to check if the connection is being served by `SignalR` middleware

**Context**

I am working on a `AspNet 5 SignalR` with `JwtBearerAuthentication` (`Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer`).

In order to authenticate SignalR connection with token reliably on all platforms, I have to use query string to pass it.

**Use case**

The actual code where I need this can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/master/samples/SignalR/HelloSignalR/Startup.cs#L50-L57):

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options => {
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {
        // Note: for SignalR connections, the default Authorization header does not work,
        // because the WebSockets JS API doesn't allow setting custom parameters.
        // To work around this limitation, the access token is retrieved from the query string.
        OnReceivingToken = context => {
            // Note: when the token is missing from the query string,
            // context.Token is null and the JWT bearer middleware will
            // automatically try to retrieve it from the Authorization header.

            // >>> Here i need to check if the connection is served by signalr
            // >>> And if not, simply not take token from query string
            context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Write a custom middleware to detect the presence of the token in the querystring?

Comment: If you looked at the "actual code where I need this" it already behaves as a middleware of sorts. Not much of a difference.
If you know a way of determining if the connection is served by SignalR in a middleware, I'm sure I could use same logic where I need it :)

Comment: What is "actual code where I need this"?  Posting that will likely increase the chance of you getting an answer.

Comment: I fixed the link (was changed and 404'ed) and added code excerpt. If it is still not clear why I need it, just ask :)

Comment: @DovydasNavickas How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Jenan No, still always getting `access_token` from query string. In a way it is convenient, because you can test authenticated HTTP GET requests easily in your browser.

Comment: @DovydasNavickas How do you check if the access token has not expired?

Comment: That is done by JWT middleware. If it's expired, an exception is thrown:
fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware[0]
      Exception occurred while processing message
      System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to `HttpContext` there, so you could inspect the path to see if the request is being made to the signalr endpoint;

```
OnReceivingToken = context => {
    var isSignalR = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/signalr");
}
```

Comment: This is of course a solution, but it's not flexible enough. As the code is going into sample repository for other people to look at and use it, the code has to be flexible and automatically check that, not an error-prone way of requiring to add every endpoint into the check.
It might be impossible to check that in SignalR now, but I'll definitely point this for SignalR 3.

Comment: Doesn't at the moment look trivial to solve this in a nicer way.  I thought inspecting `ApplicationBuilder` might be a go, but the components are saved to a [private variable](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/ApplicationBuilder.cs#L16).